# AdminLTE JS code for datepicker not giving me data on 'Todays' date because of active link. How to remove active link in JS code?

Tags: javascript, adminlte

Based on the AdminLTE bootstrap template. If i select the datepicker as 'Today' the page is not refreshing and giving me data.

Refer image attached[image]

The js code associated is as follows:

```
$('.daterange').daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
      Today: [moment(), moment()],
      Yesterday: [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    },
   // startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
   startDate: moment(),
   endDate: moment()
  }, function (start, end) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-alert
     document.getElementById("selectSdateInput").value=start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     document.getElementById("selectEdateInput").value=end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
     document.getElementById("formBean").submit();   
    
   // alert('You chose: ' + start.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'))
  })
```

what i found out is the active link is placed on 'Today' by default. If i remove the active link i believe the code will work. How to remove the active link in this JS code. please provide the JS code to remove the active link.

If i try to remove the below code

```
// startDate: moment().subtract(29, 'days'),
   startDate: moment(),
   endDate: moment()
```

it will still point the active link by default in 'Today'

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sole by using the following JS code. We need to create a JS that will read the event handler manually.

```
$('.daterange').daterangepicker({
  ranges: {
    Today: [moment(), moment()],
    Yesterday: [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
    'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
    'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
    'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
    'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
  },
  startDate: moment(),
  endDate: moment()
});

$('.daterange').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
  var start = picker.startDate;
  var end = picker.endDate;
  document.getElementById("selectSdateInput").value = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  document.getElementById("selectEdateInput").value = end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  document.getElementById("formBean").submit();
});
```